# How can I get started developing extensions for python IDLE?

Tags: python, editor, python-idle

How can I develop extensions in IDLE? In IDLE's preferences I've seen this and would love to learn how to make my own extensions:

[image: Extensions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<pythondir>/Lib/idlelib/extend.txt` explains how to write an extension module with an extension class.  `<pythondir>/Lib/idlelib/zzdummy.py` is an (incomplete) example extension module, with an example `ZzDummy` class .

The comment in `<pythondir>/Lib/idlelib/config-extension.def` explains how to add an entry to that file so that IDLE will incorporate an extension.  The `ZzDummy` entry is an example extension entry.  If you uncomment `ZzDummy.menudefs` in `zzdummy.py`, enable the ZzDummy extension on the Settings dialog Extensions tab, as shown in your image, and restart IDLE, `z in` and `z out` entries will appear at the bottom of the Format menu.   However, the menu entries do not work, which is why `menudef` is commented out.

You question reminded me of the existence of https://bugs.python.org/issue32631.  I have edited and merged the patch and the backports are in progress.  The changes will be in the next releases of 3.8, 3.9, and 3.10.  You can see the changes now at  https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/14491/files.  The new version of zzdummy is https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/idlelib/zzdummy.py and you could copy that into your installed idlelib for any of the above versions.